# Is the Watcher in the MCU named Uatu?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021, watcher

In *What If...?* (2021), the main character is "The Watcher", a cosmic being with the power to see all universes. He shows us various universes and finally

> breaks his vow to not interfere in order to save the multiverse from Ultron-Vision.

However, in the comics, a character also referred to as "The Watcher" is Uatu the Watcher. Is the Watcher in *What If...?* actually Uatu the Watcher canonically? I'm looking for a reference in the show that shows this, or out-of-universe confirmation by someone in authority to say such things.

Comment: No no, that’s Jeff. Jeff the Watcher. Jeff is the wright answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A.C. Bradley, the writer and producer for the show, has gone on record saying that they chose to not name Uatu deliberately so the audience focused on the story that was being told. That said she specifically names the character as Uatu in the interview, available on [YouTube here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdXl1wpkXNc&t=723s).

> I'm not fully able to discuss what Marvel might be doing with the character of the Watcher in the future. I like the idea of keeping him the Watcher because the second you name something you're saying there's more than one. So, I was like I'm just gonna refer to him as the Watcher because like for right now in the microcosm of _What If...? I like the idea that we're just focusing on him and his journey and his interaction with these characters and watching the worlds and how these worlds change him instead of going into does he have a family does he go home for thanksgiving? Does he... is there a Mrs. Uatu? Do you see his kids? Does he want kids? Is he not one of those guys who wants kid?. Like I was like no let's just focus on the Watcher. I would watch that **I don't know the home life of Uatu** and let's just focus on this notion of the Watcher and how that ties into our stories and our narrative of this notion of how these stories across the Marvel universe and storytelling across culture changes us it affects us and affects how we view our world.

Comment: The above is a slightly edited version of the YouTube autogenerated transcript so there's probably a few mistakes.

Comment: “This week on The Uatus: ‘Uatu Jr.: Dad, I’m running for student council President, and I don’t have time to make any signs!’ Uatu: Son, you should hang up the Hulk, he’s just a giant Banner anyway.’ (/laugh track)”

Comment: in response to the quote: we already know there is more than one though because we've seen three talking to whatever character Stan Lee was playing in GotG2

Comment: @NKCampbell: well, maybe. They could just be Watcher fans on their way to a costume competition.

Answer (score 13):

Confirmed as Uatu by the show's "Creative Director of Visual Development" Ryan Meinerding

> Uatu is a cherished Marvel character, and as the shepherd of the What
> If…? comic book series, he has interacted with every Avenger. Even
> more intimidating, his design has been altered by nearly as many comic
> book artists. It’s impossible not to feel somewhat uneasy when making
> those first cinematic adjustments, but it’s also a process Meinerding
> is well-versed in.
>
> **“There’s always huge challenges with a character that has as long a
> history as Uatu,”** Meinerding says. **“There are a lot of expectations
> there. People want to see certain things with him. But I think one of
> the fun components with the Watcher in the show is that, as the
> narrator, as that voice leading us into the show and explaining
> everything, the visuals reinforce his omniscient presence. He’s there,
> but not really there.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[‘What If…?’ Pushed Marvel’s Design Team Into Its Most Daring Arena](https://filmschoolrejects.com/what-if-character-design-interview/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Good answer. I'd accept both if possible, but the other one seems a little clearer.